# Swift appdelegate error - appdelegate does not not confirm to protocol

Tags: swift, appdelegate, swift-protocols

there are some codes i am writting.

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, XPageViewControllerDataSource {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)


    let pageVeiwController = XPageviewcontroller()
    pageVeiwController.dataSource = self

    self.window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: pageVeiwController)
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
func XPageNumberOfControllers() -> NSInteger {
    return 5
}
func XPageControllersTitle(index: NSInteger) -> String {
    return "ViewController"+"title"+String(index)
}
func XPageWillShowController(index: NSInteger) -> UIViewController {
    let vc = ViewController()
    return vc
}


}
```

i am writing a pure coding programme without mainstoryboard in Xcode,
this is my appdelegate.swift,   i try to implement the protocol from my XPageViewController.swift, there are 3 functions in protocol which I have already written in appdelegate. And i have also declared in XPageViewController.swift

```
var dataSource:XPageViewControllerDataSource!
    {
    didSet{
        self.numberOfControllers = self.dataSource.XPageNumberOfController()
        self.addViewToSelf()
    }
```

which is using in appdelegate

```
    pageVeiwController.dataSource = self
```

but still a error occur there, 
shows"Type 'AppDelegate' does not conform to protocol 'XPageViewControllerDataSource'"

i almost run out solutions :D 
do anyone have any ideas can help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us what the `XPageViewControllerDataSource` protocol comprises of?

Command+Click it in Xcode to view the actual protocol.

Either way, when you view the protocol it should show you what the requirements for the protocol are.

Comment: is there anywhere in the framework/library an extension of the protocol? e.g. `extension XPageViewControllerDataSource {...}`

Comment: anyhow i can not do linebreak, sorry about that ...<br/> does not work.... `protocol XPageViewControllerDataSource {  
    func XPageNumberOfController() -> NSInteger  
    func XPageControllersTitle(index: NSInteger) -> String  
    func XPageWillShowController(index: NSInteger) -> UIViewController  
} `